# JSP Scriptlet won't recognize vararg method when I provide 0 args

Tags: java, jsp, variadic-functions

I have a public static Java method with signature `getMessage(String, Locale, Object...)`, which means it will accept 0 to n Objects.

I tried calling the method from a JSP file inside of a scriptlet. (I know, inline Java in JSPs is considered bad practice, but a lot of our 10-year-old web app has it this way.) The server throws a `NoSuchMethodException`, claiming that `com.mypackage.MyClass.getMessage(String, Locale)` does not exist.

If I add a null argument to the call after Locale, it works fine. If I add a wrapper method that matches `getMessage(String, Locale)` that calls the varags version, it works fine. If I call it from a Java class, it works fine. But it won't recognize the varags method if I try to provide 0 args to it from within a scriptlet in a JSP.

Is this a bug in the jsp rendering code, or did I do something wrong in my varargs implementation?

from MyClass.java:

```
private static org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public static String getMessage(String key, Locale locale, Object... args) {
    // This section isn't really relevant; this method doesn't even get called.
    String variant = locale.getVariant();
    if (variant != null && variant.length() > 0 && variant.charAt(0) == '_' && FooLocale.hasFooLocale(variant)) {
        FooLocale fooLocale = FooLocale.lookupFooLocale(variant);
        if (fooLocale.isChangedKey(key)) {
            return applicationContext.getMessage(key + '.' + variant, args, new Locale(locale.getLanguage(), locale.getCountry()));
        }
    }

    return applicationContext.getMessage(key, args, locale);
}

// Added this wrapper method because the above one wasn't working.
public static String getMessage(String key, Locale locale) {
    return getMessage(key, locale, (Object[])null);
}
```

From example.jsp:

```
<%-- This should use the vararg version if there's no wrapper.
But if the wrapper isn't present, this causes an error instead. --%>
<%= MyClass.getMessage("heading.ContactInfo", locale) %>

...

<%-- This should always use the vararg version --%>
<%= MyClass.getMessage("errors.InputIsInvalid", locale, "Name") %>
```

Comment: can you post your effort i mean code?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is simply a bug or limitation of JSP scriplets. If anyone finds a solution or an answer, please post it.